# removing column and rows from DataTable using Linq

Tags: c#, database, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable as an input which contains many columns and rows,

this is a sample table:

[image: Input]

I want get only the column Weather(sunny rows) with the column Play (any value)

so the output can be another DataTable like this:

[image: Output]

So any idea can help me a lot, thank you :)

Comment: You strictly need a DataTable as a result? Why not a list?

Comment: I need tow columns as output, so list will contain what exactly ?

Comment: You can see my answer, you get a list with the values needed. Another DataTable would be really unuseful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the result has to another `DataTable`? I'd simply use a named or anonymous type.

```
var filtered = sourceTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
.Where(x => x.Field<string>("WEATHER") == "sunny")
.Select(x => new
{
    Weather = x.Field<string>("WEATHER"),
    Play = x.Field<string>("PLAY")
})
.ToList();
```

Then you can use it as

```
foreach (var item in filtered)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Weather ={0}, Play = {1}", item.Weather,item.Play));
}
```

If you need the result to be`DataTable`, you can create one and add the rows manually.

Comment: So if I want to do another Linq statements, it is okey to be done on the new list ?

Comment: I may need to do group by on the new list for example

Comment: @MBH Group by what column? You have only the filtered data in the list.

Comment: It supposed to count how many YESes and NOs in the other list

Comment: Yes you can do. But that will result yes/no of only sunny weather. I assume that's what you want.

Comment: @MBH Yes. `foreach (var groupped in filtered.GroupBy(x => x.Play)) {int groupCount = groupped.Count();}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77435/discussion-between-mbh-and-sriram-sakthivel).

Comment: I already answered your question. If you need more question ask another question please.

Answer (score 1):

If it's ok to get an anonymous list you can do like this:

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(x => x["WEATHER"] == "sunny")
               .Select(x => 
                     new 
                        { 
                            WEATHER = x["WEATHER"] as string, 
                            PLAY = x["PLAY"] as string 
                        });
```