# linq exclude certain columns when copying to a new datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create an excel sheet using OpenXML and the LoadfromDataTable. I'm not married to that function if there is better. I am trying to exclude datatable columns so they don't show up in the excel sheet. For example, I have a datatable with Columns "ID", "Name" and "Address".

```
   ID Name  Address
   1  Name1 So SO Street
   2  Name2 Do Do Street
```

What I am trying to do is create a new Datatable with just the columns Name and address and exclude ID.

I have a linq query that gets the list of columns that I would like to see in the new datatable as so:

```
var columns = dt1.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(c => c.ColumnName != "ID").ToList();
```

and I was trying to figure how to use that list to create a new datatable just with those columns in the list.

Comment: Could you be more specific and provide more details? I don't get what you mean by "__how to create a new datatable using linq with columns from the "column" variable__"

Comment: I believe you will find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type-results

Comment: I know I can do that but I am trying to exclude 2 columns and select 10+ to create a new datatable of data

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151388/removing-column-and-rows-from-datatable-using-linq?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to do this by creating a new `DataTable` of a defined `DataView`. To show an example let's create `table1`:

```
DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
table1.Columns.Add("ID");
table1.Columns.Add("Value1");
table1.Columns.Add("Value2");

table1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0, "zero", "nothing" });
table1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "one", "single" });
```

Now you need to specify the columns you want to have in your new `table2` by filtering the columns of `table1`. In our example we want all columns except "ID":

```
string[] columns = table1.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
    .Where(c => c.ColumnName != "ID")
    .Select(c => c.ColumnName).ToArray();
```

Using this columns you are able to create the new `table2`:

```
DataTable table2 = new DataView(table1).ToTable(false, columns);
```

As result `table2` looks like

```
Value1 | Value2
-------|--------
zero   | nothing
one    | single
```

Answer (score 0):

From your datatable you can select only few columns by using **.Select**

```
var result = from a in new DataContext().DataColumn
                 where a.ColumnName != "ID"
                 select new {a.NotForExcel, a.ExcelColumn1, a.ExcelColumn2 };

var ExcelList = result.AsEnumerable()
                              .Select(o => new DataColumn {
                                               Column1 = o.ExcelColumn1, 
                                               Column2 = o.ExcelColumn2 
                              }).ToList();
```